# RegEx pattern to limit dashes in these circumstances

Tags: regex, delphi, pattern-matching, filenames, pascalscript

### Scenario

I'm using a 3rd party file renaming software which is written in Delphi and has pascal-script support: http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer

The application allows the usage of regular expressions to rename files. this means that if what I need to do with a filename cannot be accomplished only using one RegEx, then I could use simultaneous various expressions or also a pascal-script code to accommodate the filename until I can properly format the filename for the needs of this question or anything else...

### Problem

I need to format song filenames like these below, in these filenames the "**...featuring artist**" part is at the right of the string, I need to match that and position it in the left part of the string.

- **Carbin & Sirmark - Sorry Feat. Sevener**
- **Kristjan Cash Cash - Take Me Home Feat. Bebe Rexha (Revoke Remix)**

To make this simple to understand, we could imaginary *tokenize* the filename like this:

```
[0]ARTIST   [1]DASH   [2]TRACK   [3]FEAT_ARTIST   [4]POSSIBLE_ADDITIONAL_INFO_INSIDE:()[]{}
```

Then what I need to do with a RegEx, is format the filename to positionate the *tokens* in this order:

```
[0]ARTIST   [3]FEAT_ARTIST   [1]DASH   [2]TRACK   [4]POSSIBLE_ADDITIONAL_INFO_INSIDE:()[]{}
```

I actually do that using this RegEx:

> \A([^-]*?)\s*-\s*(.*?)\s*([([])?((ft[.\s]|feat[.\s]|featuring[.\s])[^(){}[]]*)([)]])?(.+)?\Z

Replacing with:

> $1 $4 - $2$7

The problem begins here, because the `[0]ARTIST` and `[2]TRACK` tokens could contains dashes like for example this filename:

- **Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole**

Then, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think its just impossible to solve this in any way, because a machine can't predict when to separate one token for the other, what is a name or what isn't, because I can't know the number of dashes that contains the filename.

> For that reason, instead of looking for ingenuos perfection that could cause bad
>   filenames because the amount of dashes inside, I prefer to look for a
>   filename exclusion solution, by limiting the dashes that the expression
>   should match in the filename.

### Question

Taking as example the RegEx that I shown above to extend/improve it, how I could exclude filenames that contains an `[0]ARTIST` or an `[2]TRACK` tokens with dashes?

...Or in other words, how I can tell my RegEx to avoid modifying a filename when the filename contains more than 1 dash **before** the "**...featuring artist**" part? (not after)

Basically the Regex should determine whether `[1]DASH` is found more than once before `[3]FEAT_ARTIST`, if yes then exclude that filename (don't modify it)

I know how to limit the occurrence of a Regex group something more or less like this `([\-]){1}` to match only 1 dash occurrence, but I'm not sure how to implement it in the expression I'm using.

---

### Expected Results

Just some random examples...

One dash only before the `[3]FEAT_ARTIST` so we can know when to separate `[0]ARTIST` from `[2]TRACK` tokens.

- From: '**Carbin & Sirmark - Sorry Feat. Sevener**'
- To: '**Carbin & Sirmark Feat. Sevener - Sorry**'

One dash only before the `[3]FEAT_ARTIST` so we can know when to separate `[0]ARTIST` from `[2]TRACK` tokens. With `[4]POSSIBLE_ADDITIONAL_INFO_INSIDE:()[]{}`.

- From: '**Flight Facilities - Heart Attack Feat. Owl Eyes (Snakehips Remix)**'
- To: '**Flight Facilities Feat. Owl Eyes - Heart Attack (Snakehips Remix)**'

One dash only before the `[3]FEAT_ARTIST` so we can know when to separate `[0]ARTIST` from `[2]TRACK` tokens. With `[4]POSSIBLE_ADDITIONAL_INFO_INSIDE:()[]{}` which also contains dashes.

- From: '**Flight Facilities - Heart Attack Feat. Owl Eyes [Snake--hips Remix]**'
- To: '**Flight Facilities Feat. Owl Eyes - Heart Attack [Snake--hips Remix]**'

One dash only between `[0]ARTIST` an `[2]TRACK` tokens, but the filename doesn't have a `[3]FEAT_ARTIST` so we don't touch it.

- From: '**Fedde Le Grand - Cinematic**'
- To: '**Fedde Le Grand - Cinematic**'

One dash only between `[0]ARTIST` an `[2]TRACK` tokens, but the  `[3]FEAT_ARTIST` is before the `[1]DASH` so we don't touch it.

- From: '**Fedde Le Grand Feat. Denny White - Cinematic**'
- To: '**Fedde Le Grand Feat. Denny White - Cinematic**'

`[0]ARTIST` has dashes, so we can't know when to separate `[0]ARTIST` and `[2]TRACK` tokens, so the Regex should excludes this to don't modify this filename.

- From: '**Artist-Name - Track Name feat someone**'
- To: '**Artist-Name - Track Name feat someone**'

`[2]TRACK` has dashes, so we can't know when to separate `[0]ARTIST` and `[2]TRACK` tokens, so the Regex should excludes this to don't modify this filename.

- From: '**Artist Name - Track-Name feat someone**'
- To: '**Artist Name - Track-Name feat someone**'

`[0]ARTIST` and `[2]TRACK` tokens has dashes, so we can't know when to separate them, so the Regex should excludes this to don't modify this filename.

- From: '**Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole**'
- To: '**Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole**'

`[0]ARTIST` and `[2]TRACK` tokens has dashes and also `[3]FEAT_ARTIST` doesn't exists, again nothing to do here.

- From: '**Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track!**'
- To: '**Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track!**'

I hope this helps to understand what I need.

Comment: Just a thought, but could the string contain non-printable characters (like <STX>, <ETX>) which delimit the various parts of the string? These can be removed before printing to screen or used by the regular expression parser.

Comment: @AlainD thanks for comment, the filenames didn't contains control characters, originally in some cases I found filenames that contains special unicode dashes or other special symbols, but I remove/transform all those special chars before using the regex of this question.

Comment: What is the regex flavour in use? If you don't specify that then it's hardly surprising to get answers that don't use the same flavour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+?)\s+[fF](t|eat(uring)?)?\.?([^([\])\n]+)(.+)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cH1eE6/4)

and use replace with: `$1 Feat.$5 - $2$6`

I tried it with ReNamer and Regex101, and it works also if there is `-` ( + `-` + ) in artist name, like `artist - name`, BUT it will fail if there is such fragment in title part.

The `^(.+)\s+-\s+` part use a greedy quantifier `.+` before a sequence space-dash-space, which is treated as delimiter between artist name and title of track. So it will match as much as it can, up to last occurrence of `-`, because of that, it will "ignore" the dashes with spaces in names of artist, but it will case invalid match, if such element occur in track title. So the:

- `Artist - name - track title feat. someone` - it will be matched and
  modified properly,
- `Artist name - track - title feat. someone` - it will fail, as text
  will be splitted on last dash.

Instead of `(ft[.\s]|feat[.\s]|featuring[.\s])` I used `[fF](t|eat(uring)?)?\.?` which match similar, but should work faster (it should restrain backtracing a little bit).

in my demo, there is a `+` instead `\s+` (like above) as it would match multiline in the demonstration, and show invalid results, but in oneline cases, like in your problem, it should work fine.

Comment: Thankyou but what syntax you've used to build that expression? I think Delphi (or at least the app I'm using) does not support this: `(?:...)`, I can't use it.

Comment: then try with `(.+?)\s-\s*(.+?)[fF]eat(uring)?.([^([\])\n]+)(.+)?` and replece with `\1 Feat. \4 - \2 \5` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cH1eE6/2)

Comment: Seems closer, but it fails with some of of the examples I given above, it modifies `Artist-Name - Track Name feat someone.txt` with `Artist Feat. Someone - Name-Track Name.txt` or else `Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole.txt` with `Dj E Feat. Dj Ass-Hole-Nergy C-21 - My Super-Hero Track!.txt` in that cases the regex should don't modify the original string.

Comment: The regex that you shown in your comment is very close, it just need to avoid modify the filename when it founds more than one " - " before the "...feat" part. 

This regex solves that specific problem `(.+?)(\s-\s*){1}(.+?)[fF]eat(uring)?.([^([\])\n]+)(.+)?` with replace `$1 $2 $3 Feat. $5` but it only works for filenames like this: `Dj E-nergy C - 21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole`, no others, because the replace order I did ...so my regex at all is wrong.

Comment: @ElektroStudios in your file names, in fragments like `E-nergy` or `C - 21`, is `-` could be separated from words by space? there is no such situation in any of your examples from question, but now you put it into comments. My regex should work if only one `-` is sourrounded by spaces, the `-` which separate artist from title.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I tried ReNamer with my regex, and it is working  as you expect with examples you presented in question, so it if is not what you want, pleas post specific examples with additional details

Comment: @ElektroStudios I updated answer, I test it in ReNamer, and it work fine in my opinion

Comment: the only example I failed to publish is a filename with space+dash+space (" - ") just like this: `Dj E-nergy C - 21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole` but seems that you've solved that situation with the last edit of your RegEx! Thankyou! please give me a day to perform a further test then I accept your answer, I think now is working perfect the regex in all expected scenarios, no matter how much dashes i put, fine!, but I need to be secure doing better tests. thanks again!

Comment: I udpated answer once again, couse I forgot to add a `ft.` as one of alternatives for _feat._. This modification will change a groups order, so the replace line need to be chaged also

Comment: I tested the new edit, but the RegEx fails for this filename `Artist Name - Track - Name Feat. Someone.txt` ir replaces it by: `Artist Name - Track Feat. Someone - Name.txt` it shouldn't modify the filename because it has more than one " - " before the "...feat". Could you do something about that? seems this problem is the same you've talked about in your last answer edit.

Comment: Unfortunetely, I cannot fix it, regex cannot recognize which dash with spaces is proper one, all you can do is to set regex to match first dash or last dast, or match dash with spaces near to another characteristic part. In case `Artist Name - Track - Name Feat. Someone.txt` there is no regex solution, regex will not recognize which is title which artist name. the workaround would be to not match the files where two or more space-dash-space sequence appear before feat. part.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing you need to realize/change is that there is a distinguishable difference between the "separator hyphen" and the "embedded hyphens". Namely none of the embedded hyphens would have spaces on BOTH sides (I expect; you'll need to verify that). All you should need to do is change the beginning of your regexp above from `\A([^-]?)\s-\s*` to `\A(.?)\s-\s+`...

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but the modification you suggestioned didn't work for any example! do you know why?.

Comment: There may be other problems with the regexp as (mis?)displayed in your question. Without seeing more details, I couldn't say why. Try "\A(.*)\s-\s+"...

Answer (score 1):

I put all your file names into text editor UltraEdit version 22.10:

```
Carbin & Sirmark - Sorry Feat. Sevener
Kristjan Cash Cash - Take Me Home Feat. Bebe Rexha (Revoke Remix)
Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole
Flight Facilities - Heart Attack Feat. Owl Eyes (Snakehips Remix)
Flight Facilities - Heart Attack Feat. Owl Eyes [Snake--hips Remix]
Fedde Le Grand - Cinematic
Fedde Le Grand Feat. Denny White - Cinematic
Artist-Name - Track Name feat someone
Artist Name - Track-Name feat someone
Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole
Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track!
```

With the Perl regular expression search string

```
^(.+) - (.+?) ((?:featuring|feat\.?|ft\.?) +(?:[^\r\n (\[{]| (?![(\[{]))+)
```

and the replace string

```
$1 $3 - $2
```

those file names were modified with a case insensitive **Replace All** to

```
Carbin & Sirmark Feat. Sevener - Sorry
Kristjan Cash Cash Feat. Bebe Rexha - Take Me Home (Revoke Remix)
Dj E-nergy C-21 feat Dj Ass-hole - My Super-hero track!
Flight Facilities Feat. Owl Eyes - Heart Attack (Snakehips Remix)
Flight Facilities Feat. Owl Eyes - Heart Attack [Snake--hips Remix]
Fedde Le Grand - Cinematic
Fedde Le Grand Feat. Denny White - Cinematic
Artist-Name feat someone - Track Name
Artist Name feat someone - Track-Name
Dj E-nergy C-21 feat Dj Ass-hole - My Super-hero track!
Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track!
```

which looks like is what you want. UltraEdit uses the Boost Perl regular expression library.

If the file renaming tool supports also negative lookaheads and greedy matching behavior, the expression perhaps useful for this task is:

```
\A(.+) - (.+?) ((?:featuring|feat\.?|ft\.?) +(?:[^ (\[{]| (?![(\[{]))+)
```

and the replace string is also:

```
$1 $3 - $2
```

---

**Explanation of the search string:**

`^` ... start of a line
`\A` ... start of buffer

`(.+) -`  ... a **greedy** expression which matches any character 1 or more times (except newline characters) up to **last** occurrence of <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>dash</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> in a marking group not including  `-`  which results still in a positive match for the **entire expression**.

`(.+?)`  ... a **non greedy** expression also in a capturing group matching any character (except newline characters) one or more times up to next occurrence of a space and ...

`(?:featuring|feat\.?|ft\.?) +` ... word `featuring` OR abbreviation `feat` with or without a dot OR abbreviation `ft` with or without a dot AND 1 or more spaces.

`(` ... begin of third capturing group.

`(?:[^\r\n (\[{]| (?![(\[{]))+` ... a non marking group matching either

- a character **not** being

  - a carriage return or a line-feed (UE search string only), or
  - an opening parenthesis, or
  - an opening square bracket, or
  - an opening brace

or

- a space with using a negative lookahead expression checking if next character **not** being

  - an opening parenthesis, or
  - an opening square bracket, or
  - an opening brace

one or more times. In other words this last expression matches everything up to end of file name or `(` or `[` or `{` not including the space left to those characters to avoid getting <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>dash</kbd> after `FEAT_ARTIST` after replace.

`)` ... finally ends third capturing group.

---

**Edit 1:** Also working (in UltraEdit) is the search string:

```
^(.+) - (.+?) ((?:featuring|feat|ft)[ .]+(?:[^\r\n (\[{]| (?![(\[{]))+)
```

which would except also `featuring.`, but makes expression a little bit easier.

---

**Edit 2:** Also working (in UltraEdit) is the search string:

```
^((?:.(?! - ))+.) - ((?:.(?! - ))+) ((?:featuring|feat|ft)[ .]+(?:[^\r\n (\[{]| (?![(\[{]))+)
```

which ignores all lines containing two <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>dash</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> left to `FEAT_ARTIST`.

This expression matches character by character with using a negative lookahead if string after current character is not <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>dash</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>. This is allowed for first capturing group which selects the string up to last character left of first <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>dash</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, but for second capturing group there should be no more <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>dash</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> as this would definitely result in a negative result for the entire expression.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but those regular expressions seems are not supported by the RegEx motor of the app (I'm not sure if author used Delphi/Object-pascal or Pascal-script for that). this throws error of "**Unknown modifier**" at position 41 `^(.+) - (.+?) ((?:featuring|feat\.?|ft\.?) +(?:[^\r\n (\[{]| (?![(\[{]))+)` and this at position 42 `\A(.+) - (.+?) ((?:featuring|feat\.?|ft\.?) +(?:[^ (\[{]| (?![(\[{]))+)` anyways I'll read and investigate about your explanations to find some kind of equivalent (if I'm lucky). thanks again!

Comment: I didn't understood at all how you replaced this `Dj E-nergy C-21 - My Super-hero track! feat Dj Ass-hole` for this else `Dj E-nergy C-21 feat Dj Ass-hole - My Super-hero track!`, how your expression can know the exact place where to insert the `...feat` part when a lot of dashes are in the string??? you've explained that logic?, really good job!, I wonder to find a "compatible" solution like that you have shown.

Comment: The search expression works as long as `ARTIST` or `TRACK` part does not contain a hyphen or dash with a space on left side AND a space on right side as this is used to separate the strings.

Comment: Understood, but the `ARTIST` or `TRACk` could have also a dash with spaces, then what I really need is a search expression limited to search only one **" - "**, if two **" - "** are found before `FEAT_ARTIST` then don't modify the string. Anyways unfortunately the application seems doesn't accept the syntax you used as I said. I'll keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: I have added one more search string which ignores file names with more than one " - " left to featuring artist. But this works only if the renaming tool supports negative lookaheads. If your renaming tool does not support it, get all file names into a text file and use UltraEdit to convert the text file into a batch file with __ren__ commands for those file names to change and __rem__ commands for those file names to keep.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @**m.cekiera**'s regex I solved this by using a pascal-script that prevents any replacement when more than one dash is found in the filename:

```
// Formats an audio filename that has the "...featuring artist" part at the end of filename.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// Pseudo-Example:
//
// From: [0]ARTIST_NAME  [1]DASH  [2]TRACK_TITLE  [3]FEAT_ARTIST  [4]POSSIBLE_ADDITIONAL_INFO_INSIDE:()[]{}
// To:   [0]ARTIST_NAME  [3]FEAT_ARTIST  [1]DASH  [2]TRACK_TITLE  [4]POSSIBLE_ADDITIONAL_INFO_INSIDE:()[]{}

// Real-Example:
//
// From: Carbin & Sirmark - Sorry Feat. Sevener.mp3
// To:   Carbin & Sirmark Feat. Sevener - Sorry.mp3

// Known limitations:
//
// • If [0]ARTIST_NAME or [2]TRACK_TITLE parts contains any " - " the script will not work properlly.
//   By default the script prevents any replacement on that kind of filenames, so don't worry.


var
  rgxPattern: string;
  rgxReplace: string;
  dashCount: integer;
  baseName: string;
  extension: WideString;

begin

  baseName  := WideExtractBaseName(FileName)
  extension := WideExtractFileExt(FileName);

  // The regular expression that matches the filename parts.
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807698/regex-pattern-to-limit-dashes-in-these-circumstances
  rgxPattern := '^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+?)\s+[fF](t|eat(uring)?)?\.?([^([\])\n]+)(.+)?$'
  rgxReplace := '$1 Feat.$5 - $2$6'

  // The amount of " - " that contains the filename.
  dashCount := high(MatchesRegEx(baseName, '\s-\s' , false));

  // If only one " - " is found then...
  If (dashCount = 0) Then
    begin // Do the replacement.
      baseName := ReplaceRegEx(baseName, rgxPattern, rgxReplace, false, true)
      FileName := baseName + extension;
    end;

end.
```