# Fix RegEx to properly capture text inside parenthesis

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

### SCENARIO

---

Time ago I asked a question to format music filenames in certain conditions:

- [RegEx pattern to limit dashes in these circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807698/regex-pattern-to-limit-dashes-in-these-circumstances)

However, I noticed too late that the accepted answer is wrong, because it can capture any word starting with "F". But this is not a problem/question, I solved it just by restoring the `ft|feat|featuring` OR group.

So finally from que question linked above, I ended up using this expression:

```
pattern := '^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+?)\s+(ft|feat|featuring)[\.\s]*([^([\])]+)(.+)?$' 
replace := '$1 Feat. $4 - $2$5'
```

Well, now, having these filenames to test:

1. Black Coast - Trndsttr
2. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather)
3. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Lucian Remix)
4. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather) (Lucian Remix)
5. Black Coast - Trndsttr Feat. M. Maggie
6. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feat. M. Maggie)
7. Black Coast - Trndsttr Feat. M. Maggie (Lucian Remix)
8. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feat. M. Maggie) (Lucian Remix)
9. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Lucian Remix) Feat. M. Maggie
10. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Lucian Remix) (Feat. M. Maggie)
11. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather) (Lucian Remix) Feat. M. Maggie
12. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather) (Lucian Remix) (Feat. M. Maggie)
13. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather) Feat. M. Maggie (Lucian Remix)
14. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather) (Feat. M. Maggie) (Lucian Remix)
15. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather) (Feat. M. Maggie) Lucian Remix
16. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather) Feat. M. Maggie Lucian Remix

The expected results are these:

(from 1 to 4 no changes, and 16 is an assumable false positive, it is in essence the same as 5, 9 and 11.)

1. Black Coast - Trndsttr
2. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather)
3. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Lucian Remix)
4. Black Coast - Trndsttr (Feather) (Lucian Remix)
5. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr
6. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr
7. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Lucian Remix)
8. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Lucian Remix)
9. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Lucian Remix)
10. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Lucian Remix)
11. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Feather) (Lucian Remix)
12. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Feather) (Lucian Remix)
13. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Feather) (Lucian Remix)
14. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Feather) (Lucian Remix)
15. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie - Trndsttr (Feather) Lucian Remix
16. Black Coast Feat. M. Maggie Lucian Remix - Trndsttr (Feather)

### PROBLEM

---

The expression that I mentioned works perfect for all the filenames except for the cases where the **Feat...** part is grouped inside parenthesis (or brackets, whatever).

Then I tried to adapt the RegEx for the aggrupations condition:

```
pattern := '^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+?)\s+([\[\(\{])?\s*(ft|feat|featuring([\.])?\s+)((.+)[^\]\)\}])?\s*(.+)?$'
```

But I ended messing my head and missing things, because it also captures the first parenthesis enclosure and the following characters till the end.

I need some help with this.

### Question

---

How I could fix/improve my expression to treat the mentioned filenames to get the expected results above?.

Or in other words, I need to maintain the "structure" of the expression but adding the capability to capture the **Feat...** part when it is inside parenthesis/brackets to properly format the filename.

PS: Please remember that I'm under pascal-script's RegEx syntax and their limitations (which I'm not sure about them).

### IMPORTANT EDIT:

I discovered that the author of the software that has this limitations it has support to run an external app from its pascal-script editor, so I can launch a CLI app written in .Net to perform the regex replacement, then I'm now under C#/Vb.Net RegEx motor improvements, nice!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
^(?P<artist>.+?(?=\s-\s))          # artist with pos. lookahead
\s-\s                              # space - space
(?P<title>.+?(?=(?:\(?Feat\.)|$))  # title with pos. lookahead 
\(?                                # optional open parenthesis
    (?P<artist2>Feat\.[^()\n]+)?   # artist2 with Feat. before
\)?                                # optional closing parenthesis
(?P<subtitle>.+)?$                 # optional subtitle
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iQ2aG4/1).
Problem is that the dashes do not always match (maybe some additional programming logic?)

Comment: Thanks for answer and the effort put on designing the expression... but as I specified I'm under pascal-script, not php syntax and their improvements, the expression cannot run, before and after removed the named groups the compiler says unrecognized modifier (not exactlly where): **^(.+?(?=\s-\s))\s-\s(.+?(?=(?:(?Feat\.)|$))(?(Feat\.[^()\n]+)?)?(.+)?$**, your expression can be adapted to my circunstances\language?.

Comment: Please, forget what I said about pascal-script, now I found that the author of the software that has this limitations it has support to run an external app from its pascal-script editor, so I will develop a simple app written in C#, I will start translating the PHP syntax and Ill come here to accept the answer or expose any problem about the dashes that you commented. Thanks for all!

Comment: Considering my needs, this is the final RegEx with .Net Syntax: "**^(?<artist>.+?(?=\s*-\s*))\s*-\s*(?<title>.+?(?=(?:\(?(ft|feat|featuring)\.)|$))\(?(?<feat>(ft|feat|featuring)\.[^()\n]+)?\)?(?<subtitle>.+)?$**" and the replacement: "**${artist} ${feat} - ${title}${subtitle}**" plus a minor additional replacement of the double whitespaces. Thanks for your answer!.

Comment: With your amazing skills, It would be great if you could fix that minor problem of whitespaces to gain performance by avoiding additional replacement steps... this regex will be used to replace thousands of filenames daily, and just only initializing an external app to perform each replacement costs much time. I hope I'm not asking for too much!, anyways your regex is great as its.